# Applying order property to flex items in different containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have this html:

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-item-1">stuff</div> 
    <div class="flex-item-3">stuff</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item-2">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to order those 1,2,3 as if the `row` div doesn't exist?

I tried:

```
.flex { display:flex; flex-direction: column; }
.flex-item-1 { order: 1; }
.flex-item-2 { order: 2; }
.flex-item-3 { order: 3; }
```

But since they aren't originally of the same parent/child nesting level (or even child container), this doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current HTML structure, that is not possible.

The `order` property applies only to flex items that are *siblings* in the same flex container.

(And keep in mind that `.row` isn't even a flex container. So the children are not flex items.)

You can use `order` to re-arrange `.row` and `.flex-item-2`.

If you apply `display: flex` or `inline-flex` to `.row`, you can then use `order` to re-arrange `.flex-item-1` and `.flex-item-3`.

But because they have different parents, the first two cannot be re-arranged with the latter two.